# Google App Script, get SpreadSheet column filter criteria

Tags: filter, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

As the title, I had a column with filter in a spreadsheet. Now I wish to get that column filter criteria, make some change to it then apply it to the spreadsheet. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Many thanks,
Minh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it as of today. There is [issue 524](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524) in the Issue tracker for a similar request. Please star it to register your interest in the same.